# What is the best way to send Github Pull Requests for iOS Storyboards / Xibs?

Tags: ios, github, uistoryboard, pull-request

I was also wondering this, because it often happens that the raw content is too vague. How can I communicate the changes in hierarchy, the new architecture etc. without possibly throwing the entire storyboard?

Comment: question is not clear.. pls elaborate.. are you trying to understand changes done in storyboard by others?

Comment: That's right. Is there a nice standard to do prs containing storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

I use sourcetree for reviewing deltas in all of my files including storyboards.
Storyboards are harder to review than source files but i find the main element for the change and then analyze the exact change. Agreed its not the most fun part of my day